# How to select a row by name and also the previous row in bash or python?

Tags: python, bash, select, grep, row

Imagine that we have this data:

```
##sequence-region P51451 1 505
##sequence-region P22223 1 829
P22223  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   655 677 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255 
##sequence-region Q01518 1 475
##sequence-region Q96MP8 1 289
##sequence-region Q9HCJ2 1 640
Q9HCJ2  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   528 548 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255 
##sequence-region P48059 1 325
##sequence-region Q9UHB6 1 759
##sequence-region P16581 1 610
P16581  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   557 578 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255
```

And the final output would be to get the rows that contain the word '*transmembrane*' and its corresponding top row only:

```
##sequence-region P22223 1 829
P22223  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   655 677 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255 
##sequence-region Q9HCJ2 1 640
Q9HCJ2  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   528 548 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255 
##sequence-region P16581 1 610
P16581  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   557 578 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255
```

I am trying with grep but I am a little bit stuck

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) (the standard `grep` on Linux) and your data are in the file `data.txt` you can use:

```
grep -w Transmembrane --before-context=1 --no-group-separator data.txt
```

- The `-w` option will cause the match to apply to only whole words in the input.  So, for instance, `Transmembrane123` won't be matched.  That might not be what you want.
- `--before-context=1` causes `grep` to print one line in the input before every matched line.
- `--no-group-separator` causes `grep` to print no separator between groups of matched line and previous line.  Normally it prints a separator line containing `--`.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `python` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
##sequence-region P51451 1 505
##sequence-region P22223 1 829
P22223  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   655 677 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255 
##sequence-region Q01518 1 475
##sequence-region Q96MP8 1 289
##sequence-region Q9HCJ2 1 640
Q9HCJ2  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   528 548 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255 
##sequence-region P48059 1 325
##sequence-region Q9UHB6 1 759
##sequence-region P16581 1 610
P16581  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   557 578 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255
```

then create file `gettransmembrane.py` holding

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    if "Transmembrane" in line:
        print(prevline,end="")
        print(line,end="")
    prevline = line
```

then

```
python gettransmembrane.py file.txt
```

output

```
##sequence-region P22223 1 829
P22223  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   655 677 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255
##sequence-region Q9HCJ2 1 640
Q9HCJ2  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   528 548 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255
##sequence-region P16581 1 610
P16581  UniProtKB   Transmembrane   557 578 .   .   .   Note=Helical;Ontology_term=ECO:0000255;evidence=ECO:0000255
```

Explanation: [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) is module from python standard library(1), for each line I do print it and previous line if it does has `Transmembrane` substring, note that `prevline = line` is done *after* printing. I do specify empty `str`s as `end`s because lines already have newlines at their ends.

(1) if you are limited to processing one file which name you know in advance you might elect to use simple file reading using `open`, using `fileinput` allows you to use more than 1 file (akin to `cat` command) or using `stdin`, so if you have above as output of another command you do not have to make temporary file, but can do pipe output of said command into `python gettransmembrane.py`